# Little Pests with White cotton around them

Tags: pest-control, pest-damage

I see little pests with white cottons around them on my plant.

[image: Pest Picture 1]

[image: Pest Picture 2]

How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are Mealybugs (Pseudococcidae) and you want to do something about them because they bring other problems like mold with them.  Wash the plant down with insect soap which you can get at a hardware store or garden center.  If the leaves are sticky wash them down with cotton balls and rubbing alcohol.